# java array модифицировать строки

Tags: java, массивы, строки

В задаче ***Ввести n слов с консоли. Найти слово, в котором число различных
символов минимально. Если таких слов несколько, найти первое из них.*** не могу понять как обработать слова чтобы не было одинаковых букв(символов). Какой - нибудь простой алгоритм. Задумка такая: с консоли занести слова в массив - затем обработать чтобы не было дублируемых символов-букв и занести в новый массив.

Comment: пробовали `HashSet` ?

Comment: решить необходимо без коллекций

Comment: вы же знаете, что строка - это коллекция символов? Как вы собираетесь без коллекций хотя бы слова и строки получать?

Answer (score 0):

Без коллекций - имелось ввиду без `util.Collection`? Тогда вот вариант

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        private static String inputText;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                inputText = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(findWordOfMinDifferentChars(inputText));
            }
        }

        private static String findWordOfMinDifferentChars(String text){
            String[] words = text.split(" ");
            String wordOfMinDiffChars = words[0];
            int  minCountOfDifferentChars = words[0].length();
            for (String word : words) {
                char [] chars = word.toCharArray();
                int currentCount = getCountDifferentChars(chars);
                if(currentCount<minCountOfDifferentChars) {
                    minCountOfDifferentChars = currentCount;
                    wordOfMinDiffChars = word;
                }
            }
            return wordOfMinDiffChars;
        }

        private static int getCountDifferentChars(char[] chars) {
            int countOfDifferentChars = 0;
            int countOfMatchingChars = 0;
            char charToCompare;
            for (char var1 : chars) {
                int compareCount = 0;
                charToCompare = var1;
                for (char var2 : chars) {
                    if (charToCompare == var2) {
                        compareCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (compareCount == 1)
                     countOfDifferentChasr++;
                else
                    countOfMatchingChars++;
            }

            return countOfDifferentChars + countOfMatchingChars/2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо! это уже решение